# css media query to handle new high resolution mobiles whilst ignoring tablets

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

According to my research;
new smart phones portrait resolution is up to 800px
tablets miniumum portrait resolution 600px

Now I'm trying to use media queries to render mobile css to handheld devices supporting resolutions up to 800px but the problem I'm having is older tablets like the ipad1 with a 768px portrait resolution are also rendering the mobile css.

I need to ensure that tablets + desktop pcs from 600px and higher render the widescreen css whilst mobile phones with a max portrait resolution of 800px render the mobile css.

How can I do this despite the crossover of mobile & tablet widths?

this is my current setup...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,
user-scalable=0,width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 800px)" 
href="/css/mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 600px)"
href="/css/widescreen.css" />
```

thanks in advance
Omar.

UPDATE:

the following 2 in 1 media query seems to fit my purpose. I've tested on samsung galaxy s2, google nexus and iphone4 and it seems to be working fine. need to verify tablets.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media='only screen and (max-width:480px) and    
(orientation: portrait), only screen and (max-width:800px) and (orientation:  
landscape)' href="mobile.css" />
```

Comment: This is becoming increasingly irritating (I was just getting ready to post a question, myself).  There are phones running 1280x720 and tablets running 1920x1080.  Your portrait/landscape idea won't work for those kinds of resolutions.  I do not want my desktop layout (meant for 20"+ monitors) to display that way on a 10" tablet.  I know there are dpi queries, but we'll be designing on a device-level (at that point).  Maybe we can start using "width:2in".  Hehehe...

Comment: you can also specify with media="handheld and bla" instead of screen.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments as I found some new information...[According to W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#x39), 1px = 0.75pt and 1pt = 1/72in, so trying to use inches to over-come the high-resolution device problem doesn't work (it just converts px to in).  I found this out when my 12.1", 1280x800px, laptop showed styles from a 12-14" media query while my 11.6", 1366x768px, laptop showed styles from a 14"+ media query.  [This W3 page](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#units) has a box that is supposed to be 1in tall, but it's about 3/4in, on my 11.6".

Answer (score 1):

I think the philosophy you're trying to base your media queries on is flawed from the start: As quoted often by Ethan (the "inventor" of the technique) breakpoints shouldn't derive from screen/device sizes but from how the content fits naturally to the page.
Start building mobile-first with basic styles for typography and color, then as your screen grows, use min-width:500px (for example) to add some layout/columns, and keep going until you think you take advantage of the available space in desktop wide 22inch resolutions like 1900px and above. I did that for my blog ( http://www.gplus.gr/blog ) - developed only with Chrome in Desktop, and when went to check the website in other devices it worked like a charm: Android 2.x , Android 4.x , Kindle, iPad etc etc..

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

Comment: This philosophy starts to fall apart when you consider the data restrictions of mobile devices (video streaming over 3G, 4G etc. is typically to be avoided).

Comment: With everyone having 3gigabyte plans per month I think data restrictions are getting to be a problem of the past, and your comment doesn't really cancel the philosophy. You just have to use some extra layer like feature detection for example, you can not autoplay your videos, and I believe mobile browsers already handle that for you.

Comment: Disabling autoplay is not the same as not loading the video content. Further, you can't assume people will have a big enough data plan (2 or 3GB per month is not enough to stream video regularly, by the way) to handle a top-tier browsing experience.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to display video content? I've seen tons of uses for html5 video in websites, mobile included. Since when did we go back to user agent sniffing and hacks like that ? Is it 2008?