# Target ONLY smartphones with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a video background and since it takes quite a lot of MB to load that, I want to disable the video on smartphones.
The CSS itself is easy:

```
video{
   display:none;
}
```

But, how to get the media query so that it won't affect desktop and laptop screens? Because smartphones are getting higher and higher resolutions and the old method of just targeting a smaller amount of pixels (±450px e.g.) won't work with newer smartphones anymore.
The width and height of the smartphone shouldn't matter, I fixed that in my 'regular' media queries, so that the css changes when my design breaks.

Comment: Although it should, `display: none` isn't necessarily going to make your video not load. This may be better handled on the server-side where your HTML is generated.

Comment: I think this should perhaps be a broader question. In fact, it would be nice if we did have some way of querying the user's connection to see if it is appropriate to send large images or video... I can definitely see many uses for "is on limited data plan" as a query.

Comment: Use `@media only screen`

Comment: @TylerH When putting this media query in and checking it in my browser (safari on mac) it disables the video, while I want it to play. So that doesn't work. @ James Donnelly What would be the best way to prevent loading? @ Niet the Dark Absol Fine with me, I just want to prevent slow loading on smartphones :)

Comment: @Lisa You should also include specific width/height declarations so that it knows what size of device to target. Also FYI you can only ping (@Lisa) a single user per comment, so James and Niet won't get your pings.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah the SO site mentioned that haha. Your solution, wouldn't it be a problem that the newer smartphones have very high resolutions, almost the same (or higher) than some displays. This will cause 'confusion' within my css, causing the displays to have disabled videos, right?

Comment: This is a really good question to ask, which relates to @NiettheDarkAbsol 's comment. It would be great to have a canonical question on how to handle targeting high-resolution mobile devices with media queries, since the traditional method of (320px - 480px) doesn't work anymore.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738479/css-media-query-to-handle-new-high-resolution-mobiles-whilst-ignoring-tablets

Comment: @TylerH I assume from your comment that that doesn't exist yet? Would there be a workaround to check if the user is using a smartphone, for example with javascript or jquery?

Comment: @Lisa correct. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440296/reliable-way-to-detect-desktop-vs-mobile-browser or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588940/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-browser-detection-in-javascript or things like Modernizr. Search for "mobile detection" with javascript

Comment: OK, so no real solution to this issue, but thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Lisa [This list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Pseudo-BNF_%28for_those_of_you_that_like_that_kind_of_thing%29) may help you now/in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

video {
display: none;
}

}
```

This will display nothing for screen sizes with a maximum of 480 pixels (majority of smartphones)

Comment: Isn't that outdated and thus too small? Since the newer smartphones have bigger resolutions: http://www.gizmag.com/smartphone-comparison-2014-1/31787/

Comment: Well yeah in theory that would target iphone 3g/smasung s2 etc. so quite old. You can adjust accordingly based on devices you wish to target.

Comment: I don't think blackberries are still used/sold anymore. At the very least, it's *not* what people refer to when they say "smartphone".

Comment: Yeah sorry about that don't know where i got blackberry from

Comment: @user3125923 The problem with this solution is that if I adjust it to the devices I want to target, a nexus 5 (for example) won't display video, but some browsers that have a width of 1080px too, won't play video either. I'm mainly concerned about the data-usage, because I don't think mobile users will be happy when my site sucks up all their internet bundle haha.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough!This article may be of use to you: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/css/cutting-edge-device-targeting-with-css3-media-queries.html#fbid=qkj6wEuee8k